# Re train a saved model with same Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to know if i retrain my saved **model** which i ran with 4 epochs, be faster with same image set at 10 epochs?

My data set consists of 2 folders of training and validation with 5 classes and 3000 training and 1000 validation images

Comment: If by "faster" you mean execution time for 10 epochs, then there's no benefit as training a model from scratch or a pre-trained model will take the same time. But if you mean continue training the model for another 6 epochs (instead of training from scratch for 10 epochs), then its faster to use the pre-trained model.

Comment: i mean to continue training my saved model. Thanks. I got my answer and understanding how to train it. i will try to use a pre-tained model

Answer (score 0):

If you are using keras, basically calling `fit` will start from pre-existing weights and therefore the first epoch will consist of the 5th epochs. Therefore, the error will already be lower. However, beware that the processing time for each epoch will be equivalent. You will only start from a model which do not have random weights.

Comment: so this means if i want to train a model for 20 epochs, it can train it first with 10 epochs and saved it, and retrain the saved model for another 10 epochs which finally be exactly what is being trained for 20 epochs. Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes, this what I am trying to explain.